# Get Action bar overflow button click event

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is it possible to get Action bar overflow button click listener ?

I have 3 options in action bar overflow button, and I want to capture the event when user clicked on overflow button. Is is possible to capture that click event ? Any idea ?

Comment: How about you post some relevant code? Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: THis is just a simple question. I don't any code base required for explaining the problem

Comment: This [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23806593/5028508) works like a charm.

Comment: if you want to manipulate the menu items on the click of the overflow button then better do this in onCreateOptionMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

The overflow `Button` is created dynamically from a `private` inner class of the `ActionMenuPresenter`, which is an internal part of the framework that places each `MenuItem` in the `ActionBar.` There's just no way to attach a listener to it.

[ActionMenuPrestener source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuPresenter.java#L588)