# Actionbar's overflow menu open/close listener

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

I want to listen when user opens/closes the overflow menu (three dots) of ActionBar, someway like this:

```
void onOverflowMenu(boolean expanded) {
}
```

To handle open cases, I've tried `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, but it's triggered when ActionBar is constructed or when `invalidateOptionsMenu()` is called. This is not what I want.

I was able to detect overflow menu is closed if user selects a menu item in `onMenuItemSelected()`. But I also want to detect it if user closes overflow menu by tapping outside of it, by pressing back key, and all other cases.

Is there a way to implement that?

Comment: Try checking if `onMenuItemSelected()` when you press on your overflow menu. If it is triggered you could debug your application and check what you need to do in order to proper catch that event.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To catch open action in the `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    ...
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
}
```

To catch closed action, also if user touch outside of Menu view:

```
@Override
public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Also I added check if (featureId == FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) to make sure which menu has been triggered.

Comment: onMenuOpened is fired twice which is not accurate if you are trying to track analytics on the Overflow menu being opened.

Comment: Please refer to the correct solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558904/why-is-menu-of-appcompatactivity-onmenuopenedint-featureid-menu-menu-null

onPrepareOptionsMenu() will be called only once when the overflow menu is opened.

Comment: How can  we check similar scenario with overflow menu inside a fragment?

Answer (score 6):

IMHO the simplest way is to set `ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener`

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.addOnMenuVisibilityListener(new ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuVisibilityChanged(boolean isVisible) {
            if (isVisible) {
                // menu expanded
            } else {
                // menu collapsed
            }
        }
    });
}
```