# Android's AppCompatActivity.onMenuOpened signature expects a non null menu, but receives a null, instead

Tags: android, kotlin, android-appcompat

After updating build and target sdk to 29 in my project, I see that AppCompat's Activity `onMenuOpened` `menu` parameter is annotated with `@RecentlyNonNull`.

Previously, my overrided implementation of that method was:

```
override fun onMenuOpened(featureId: Int, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    // some code
    return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu)
}
```

But I'm getting this warning:

```
MainActivity.kt: (656, 46): Type mismatch: inferred type is Menu? but Menu was expected
```

And if I change the `menu: Menu?` parameter to be `menu: Menu` I'm getting this error in runtime

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter menu
```

Because, in fact, it is null. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558904/why-is-menu-of-appcompatactivity-onmenuopenedint-featureid-menu-menu-null)

I guess that this is a bug, since the system itself invokes the method with a null. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

Use AppCompatActivity 1.2.0-rc1 or higher.