# Is there a way to detect when the ActionMode overflow menu is opened and closed?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionmode

I have an `ActionBar` with an `OnMenuVisibilityListener` and a list of items. When items are selected I show an `ActionMode` with another menu. I want to listen to show/hide callbacks on the `ActionMode` overflow menu in a similar way as I do with the `ActionBar` one. Is there no way get the information that the user opened or closed the overflow menu of an `ActionMode`?

The `OnMenuVisibilityListener`is called when the `ActionBar` overflow menu is opened or closed (no list items are selected). It it not called when the ActionMode is shown (list items selected)

The `ActionMode`callback method `onPrepareActionMode` is called when the `ActionMode` is created and when the overflow menu is opened - but not when the overflow menu is closed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806383/actionbars-overflow-menu-open-close-listener

Comment: that all works fine @maja89 - for the ActionBar. It doesn't for the ActionMode.

Comment: onDestroyActionMode is called when the `ActionMode` is closed, but not when the **ActionMode menu is closed**.

Comment: There is no callback for ActionMode. If you need it you can set customView and try by adding some listener that may get called when the ActionMenu gets opened.

Comment: Don't think that will work @maja89 - as the documentation points out:
`Set a custom view for this action mode. The custom view will take the place of the title and subtitle. Useful for things like search boxes.`
Didn't try it out though, will give it a spin.

Comment: You right, sorry. My point is if current feature doesn’t support what you need try making your own and use it instead of current one.